# Error (null) with char** and struct

Tags: c

I tried to save a char** in a struct, my code is:

```
job * proceso = new_job(123,args[0],args,BACKGROUND);
printf("%s",(proceso->commando)[0]);
```

where args is the char**;

and apperar (null);
the struct is:

```
job * new_job(pid_t pid, const char * command,char ** commando, enum job_state state){
    job * aux;
    aux=(job *) malloc(sizeof(job));
    aux->pgid=pid;
    aux->state=state;
    aux->command=strdup(command);
    aux->commando=malloc(1000);
    aux->next=NULL;
    return aux;}


typedef struct job_{
   pid_t pgid; /* group id = process lider id */
   char * command; /* program name */
   char ** commando;
   enum job_state state;
   struct job_ *next; /* next job in the list */} job;


job * new_job(pid_t pid, const char * command,char ** commando, enum job_state state);

char** com;
#define new_list(name)           new_job(0,name,com,FOREGROUND)  // name must be const char *
```

I dont know the mistake;anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't see where you use the `commando` parameter in the function.

Comment: job * proceso = new_job(123,args[0],args,BACKGROUND);
printf("%s",(proceso->commando)[0]); when i execute this

Comment: Try to make a [mcve]. That `#define new_list(name)` seems to be unused as far as the code you've posted is concerned.

Comment: I think you are asking how to copy the `commando` parameter into `aux->commando`. To do that you need to know how many pointers `commando` contains.

Comment: the parameter commando is char** but i dont know how to copy that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the `char **` variable, you need to know how many pointers are in the array. It's just like in `main` where you get an `argc` that tells you how many pointers are in `argv`. Once you add that data, you can:

```
// Added num_commando parameter
job * new_job(pid_t pid, const char * command, char ** commando, size_t num_commando, enum job_state state)
{
    job * aux;
    aux=(job *) malloc(sizeof(job));
    aux->pgid=pid;
    aux->state=state;
    aux->command=strdup(command);
    // Create array of pointers
    aux->commando = malloc(sizeof(char *) * num_commando); // or sizeof(*aux->commando)
    // Duplicate every string
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_commando; i++) {
        aux->commando[i] = strdup(commando[i]);
    }
    aux->next=NULL;
    return aux;
}
```

You should also add the `num_commando` parameter to the struct so you know how many strings to `free()`.